# Error while installing "linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic" and "linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic"

Tags: package-management, upgrade, kernel, dpkg, 20.04

Today I got ubuntu updates which also included linux kernal updates. So I did `sudo apt-get upgrade` to install them. Some packages were installed followed by this error.

```
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-33-generic
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
   ...fail!
File: /var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf does not exist.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 4
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-29-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda8
I: (UUID=c3d1fbd8-36e5-49e6-b0c6-cfe8f677aa0c)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04
 linux-generic-hwe-20.04
 linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic
```

Whenever I get errors like these I usually follow these steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Most of the time these steps resolves the error. But this time `sudo apt-get autoremove` made the above logs worse. Here's the output

```
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 569827 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libccd2:amd64 (2.1-1) ...
Removing libsdformat6:amd64 (6.2.0+dfsg-2build1) ...
Removing libignition-transport4:amd64 (4.0.0+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing libignition-msgs:amd64 (1.0.0+dfsg1-5build2) ...
Removing libignition-math4:amd64 (4.0.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
Removing libqtpropertybrowser4 (4.1.2-4build1) ...
Removing linux-headers-5.4.0-28-generic (5.4.0-28.32) ...
Removing linux-headers-5.4.0-28 (5.4.0-28.32) ...
Removing linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-28-generic (5.4.0-28.32) ...
Removing linux-image-5.4.0-28-generic (5.4.0-28.32) ...
/etc/kernel/prerm.d/dkms:
dkms: removing: rtbth 3.9.6 (5.4.0-28-generic) (x86_64)

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  rtbth
Version: 3.9.6
Kernel:  5.4.0-28-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

rtbth.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-28-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

update-initramfs...

DKMS: uninstall completed.
removed '/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-28-generic.old-dkms'
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-28-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-29-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda1
done
Removing linux-modules-5.4.0-28-generic (5.4.0-28.32) ...
Removing sdformat-sdf (6.2.0+dfsg-2build1) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic (5.4.0-33.37) ...
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.4.0-33-generic
Setting up linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic (5.4.0-33.37) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-33-generic
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File: /var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf does not exist.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 4
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04:
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 depends on linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-hwe-20.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-20.04 depends on linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 (= 5.4.0.33.38); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-20.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic (5.4.0-33.37) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-33-generic
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File: /var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf does not exist.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 4
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04
 linux-generic-hwe-20.04
 linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic
```

Both the commands `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f` returns the same error log.

```
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic (5.4.0-33.37) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic (5.4.0-33.37) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-33-generic
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File: /var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf does not exist.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 4
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04:
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 depends on linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-hwe-20.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-20.04 depends on linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 (= 5.4.0.33.38); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-20.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic (5.4.0-33.37) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-33-generic
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File: /var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf does not exist.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 4
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04
 linux-generic-hwe-20.04
 linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here's the output of `locate dkms`

```
/etc/dkms
/etc/dkms/framework.conf
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkbmdeb
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkdeb
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkdsc
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkbmdeb/Makefile
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkbmdeb/debian
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkbmdeb/debian/README.Debian
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkbmdeb/debian/changelog
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkbmdeb/debian/compat
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkbmdeb/debian/control
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkbmdeb/debian/copyright
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkbmdeb/debian/rules
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkdeb/Makefile
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkdeb/debian
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkdeb/debian/README.Debian
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkdeb/debian/changelog
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkdeb/debian/compat
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkdeb/debian/control
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkdeb/debian/copyright
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkdeb/debian/dirs
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkdeb/debian/postinst
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkdeb/debian/prerm
/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkdeb/debian/rules
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms
/etc/kernel/prerm.d/dkms
/etc/modprobe.d/dkms.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/rtbth-dkms.conf
/home/akash/GitHub/rtlwifi_new/dkms.conf
/mnt/D/Ubuntu software/rtbth-dkms_3.9.6_bionic_amd64.deb
/mnt/D/Ubuntu software/rtbth-dkms_3.9.6~git20200303-1~focal1_amd64.deb
/usr/bin/dh_dkms
/usr/lib/dkms
/usr/lib/dkms/common.postinst
/usr/lib/dkms/dkms-autopkgtest
/usr/lib/dkms/dkms_autoinstaller
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-29-generic/updates/dkms
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-29-generic/updates/dkms/rtbth.ko
/usr/sbin/dkms
/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/dkms_packages.py
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/dkms
/usr/share/debhelper/autoscripts/postinst-dkms
/usr/share/debhelper/autoscripts/prerm-dkms
/usr/share/doc/dkms
/usr/share/doc/rtbth-dkms
/usr/share/doc/dkms/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/dkms/HOWTO.Debian
/usr/share/doc/dkms/README.md.gz
/usr/share/doc/dkms/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/dkms/copyright
/usr/share/doc/dkms/examples
/usr/share/doc/dkms/examples/sample-suse-10-mkkmp.spec
/usr/share/doc/dkms/examples/sample-suse-9-mkkmp.spec
/usr/share/doc/dkms/examples/sample.conf
/usr/share/doc/dkms/examples/sample.spec
/usr/share/doc/rtbth-dkms/Readme.Debian
/usr/share/doc/rtbth-dkms/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/rtbth-dkms/copyright
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/dkms
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/rtbth-dkms
/usr/share/man/man1/dh_dkms.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/dkms.8.gz
/usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Sequence/dkms.pm
/usr/src/rtbth-3.9.6/dkms.conf
/var/lib/dkms
/var/lib/dkms/dkms_dbversion
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta
/var/lib/dkms/rtbth
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/blacklist-ralink.conf
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/dkms.conf
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/make.log
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/patches
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/post_install.sh
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/post_remove.sh
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/pre_install.sh
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/patches/rt3290sta.patch
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/Makefile
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/README_STA_pci
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/RT2860STA.dat
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/RT2860STACard.dat
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/chips
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/iwpriv_usage.txt
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/rate_ctrl
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/sta
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/sta_ate_iwpriv_usage.txt
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/tools
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/chips/rt28xx.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/chips/rt30xx.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/chips/rt3290.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/chips/rtmp_chip.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/action.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/ba_action.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/client_wds.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_aes.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_asic.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_cfg.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_cmd.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_cs.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_data.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_data_pci.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_info.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_mac_pci.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_profile.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_radar.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_sanity.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_sync.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_tkip.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_video.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_wep.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/cmm_wpa.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/crypt_aes.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/crypt_arc4.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/crypt_hmac.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/crypt_md5.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/crypt_sha2.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/ee_efuse.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/ee_prom.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/eeprom.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/frq_cal.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/frq_cal_ori.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/misc.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/mlme.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/netif_block.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/ps.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/rt2860.bin_ori
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/rt2860_ori.bin
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/rt3290.bin
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/rt_channel.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/rt_led.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/rt_os_util.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/rt_rf.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/rtmp_init.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/rtmp_init_inf.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/rtmp_mcu.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/rtmp_timer.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/spectrum.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/common/uapsd.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/action.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/ags.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/ap.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/ap_diversity.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/br_ftph.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/cfg80211.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/cfg80211extr.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/chip
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/chlist.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/client_wds.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/client_wds_cmm.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/crypt_aes.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/crypt_arc4.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/crypt_hmac.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/crypt_md5.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/crypt_sha2.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/cs.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/dfs.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/dot11i_wpa.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/drs_extr.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/eeprom.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/firmware.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/frq_cal.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/iface
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/link_list.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/misc.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/misc_cmm.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/mlme.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/netif_block.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/oid.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/os
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/radar.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rt_config.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rt_led.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rt_os_net.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rt_os_util.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rt_txbf.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rtmp.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rtmp_chip.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rtmp_cmd.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rtmp_comm.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rtmp_def.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rtmp_dot11.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rtmp_iface.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rtmp_mcu.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rtmp_os.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rtmp_osabl.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rtmp_timer.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/rtmp_type.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/spectrum.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/spectrum_def.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/sta_cfg.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/uapsd.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/video.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/vr_ikans.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/vrut_ubm.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/wpa.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/wpa_cmm.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/wsc.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/chip/chip_id.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/chip/mac_pci.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/chip/rt28xx.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/chip/rt30xx.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/chip/rt3290.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/chip/rtmp_mac.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/chip/rtmp_phy.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/iface/iface_util.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/iface/rtmp_pci.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/os/rt_drv.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/os/rt_linux.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/os/rt_linux_cmm.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/include/os/rt_os.h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Kconfig.ap.soc
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Kconfig.ap.usb
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Kconfig.sta.soc
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Makefile
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Makefile.4
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Makefile.4.netif
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Makefile.4.util
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Makefile.6
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Makefile.6.netif
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Makefile.6.netif~
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Makefile.6.util
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Makefile.ap.soc
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Makefile.ap.usb
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Makefile.clean
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Makefile.libautoprovision.6
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/Makefile.sta.soc
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/br_ftph.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/cfg80211.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/cfg80211drv.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/config.mk
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/config.mk~
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/inf_ppa.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/pci_main_dev.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/rt_linux.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/rt_linux_symb.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/rt_main_dev.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/rt_pci_rbus.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/rt_proc.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/rt_profile.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/rt_rbus_pci_drv.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/rt_rbus_pci_util.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/rt_symb.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/sta_ioctl.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/vr_bdlt.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/vr_ikans.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/rate_ctrl/alg_ags.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/rate_ctrl/alg_grp.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/rate_ctrl/alg_legacy.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/rate_ctrl/ra_ctrl.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/sta/assoc.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/sta/auth.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/sta/auth_rsp.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/sta/connect.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/sta/dls.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/sta/rtmp_ckipmic.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/sta/rtmp_data.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/sta/sanity.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/sta/sta_cfg.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/sta/sync.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/sta/wpa.c
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/tools/Makefile
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/tools/bin2h
/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/tools/bin2h.c
/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.6
/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/kernel-5.4.0-29-generic-x86_64
/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.6/5.4.0-29-generic
/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.6/source
/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.6/5.4.0-29-generic/x86_64
/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.6/5.4.0-29-generic/x86_64/log
/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.6/5.4.0-29-generic/x86_64/module
/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.6/5.4.0-29-generic/x86_64/log/make.log
/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.6/5.4.0-29-generic/x86_64/module/rtbth.ko
/var/lib/dpkg/info/dkms.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/dkms.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/dkms.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/dkms.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/dkms.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/rtbth-dkms.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/rtbth-dkms.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/rtbth-dkms.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/rtbth-dkms.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/rtbth-dkms.prerm
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: What the results of `locate dkms` ? Run `updatedb` first if appropriate

Comment: I have added the output of `locate dkms` to the question itself.

Comment: `tree /var/lib/dkms/` and `dkms status` please.

Comment: @nobody Output of `tree /var/lib/dkms/` is https://pastebin.com/NEe9p4tV and `dkms status` is `rt3290sta, 2.6.0.0: added
rtbth, 3.9.6, 5.4.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed`

Comment: please show `sudo dkms remove  -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 -k --all` this is an attempt to remove this module from dkms.

Comment: @nobody It says `Error! There is no instance of rt3290sta 2.6.0.0
for kernel --all (x86_64) located in the DKMS tree.`

Comment: `sudo dkms  remove -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 --all` If this also not working; mv the folder `/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta` to another location like your $HOME.

Comment: Here's the output `------------------------------
Deleting module version: 2.6.0.0
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Error! There are no instances of module: rt3290sta
2.6.0.0 located in the DKMS tree.`

Comment: @nobodyThank you. That fixed it. Can you tell me what was the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108735/discussion-between-nobody-and-akash-karnatak).

Comment: @nobody Please post an answer and comment me so I can upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this case lies in module rt3290sta it was never installed in any kernel-version neither build. This blocks dkms. Whenever dkms is called (during a kernelupgrade) it failes.

```
sudo dkms remove -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 --all
```

removes the modul complete from kerneltree; so dkms can work again and also apt.
The other module was only installed for the lower kernelversion

```
rtbth, 3.9.6, 5.4.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Note this option is not for all Versions from dkms available.